# How to embed IronPython in a .NET application

Tags: .net, api, ironpython

Is it possible to expose an API in a .NET application by embedding a scripting language like IronPython?

How is it done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IronPython has a hosting API which can be used to execute IronPython scripts from a C#\VB application.

[This](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/dlr_hosting.shtml) is a good example of embedding IronPython inside a winforms app.Note that the hosting APIs have changed since that post. [This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/srivatsn/archive/2008/09/16/hosting-ironpython-made-easier.aspx) shows an example of the latest API

You can find the latest specs [here](http://compilerlab.members.winisp.net/dlr-spec-hosting.pdf) [Note: URL throws a 404 as of 2010-09-07]

Comment: Thanks! It would be great if you could also indicate some advantages/disadvantages of using Iron* over VSTA (apart from tech support).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it personally, but you should look at [Visual Studio Tools for Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx2008/products/bb933739.aspx)

I'm not sure if Iron Python is supported as a language for it or not, but that would be the easiest path to enable your application to be programmable.