# Calling python code(.py files) from C#

Tags: c#, python, .net, python.net

I have some python code that does a certain task.  I need to call this code from C# without converting the python file as an .exe, since the whole application is built on C#.

How can I do this?

Comment: try http://pythonnet.github.io/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your python code can be executed via [IronPython](http://www.ironpython.net/) then this is definitely the way to go - it offers the best interop and means that you will be able to use .Net objects in your scripts.

There are many ways to invoke IronPython scripts from C# ranging from compiling the script up as an executable to executing a single script file or event dynamically executing expressions as they are typed in by the user - check the documentation and post another question if you are still haivng problems.

If your script is a CPython script and can't be adapted to work with IronPython then your options are more limited.  I believe that some CPython / C# interop exists, but I couldn't find it after a quick Google search.  The best thing I can think of would be to just invoke the script directly using `python.exe` and the `Process` class.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [IronPython](http://www.ironpython.net/).

Based on your answer and comments, I believe that the best thing you can do is to embed IronPython in your application. As always, there is a relevant SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208393/how-to-embed-ironpython-in-a-net-application) about this. As Kragen said, it is important not to rely on a CPython module.

Comment: It converts the python code into an .exe file and then it is called by the c#. i want python program directly called by c# code.

Comment: @user692856 You can always compile the python code into a DLL instead of an EXE using IronPython, then reference that from your C# project.

Answer (score 1):

[Process.Start](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/prstrt.htm) is what you're after. It allows you to call another program, passing it arguments.