# Does c# support any scripting language

Tags: c#, scripting, eval

I need my superusers to write some basic expressions like (getting today, or getting first day of last month, or just returning a default int value like 40), that I can later execute and get the result. It will be used for basic scripting that will provide an optional default value for a report parameter. It would be nice if it did not require any additional installation

So does c-sharp support any scripting languages that it can happily execute and evaluate?

thanks in advance,

It's an ASP.Net application and .Net Framework 4.5

Comment: What type of scripts? Try to look at IronPython, IronRuby or other Iron* scripting languages, which use DLR.

Comment: Have you looked at scriptcs? http://scriptcs.net/

Comment: @IlyaIvanov Basic scripts that will provide an optional default value for a report parameter. It would be nice if it did not require any additional installation.

Comment: Maybe something like [csscript](http://www.csscript.net/)? `CSScript.Evaluator.Evaluate("DateTime.Today")`

Comment: Are you looking for a particular feature? A Google search for "c# scripting" gives back a lot of results. I've used Razor templates successfully for reports in the past.

Answer (score 1):

LUA is a scripting language that is able to be used from C#, take a look at [LuaInterface](http://luaforge.net/projects/luainterface/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use NLua (http://nlua.org/ https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLua/)

Super easy to integrate, and work on any platform.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) to provide "scripting" to a program. You can embed the IronPython runtime in your program and let it execute scripts passed as a string. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208393/how-to-embed-ironpython-in-a-net-application) for some examples.

You can also execute C# code compiled on the fly. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes.
There are a lot of different possible script engines for pretty much any possible scripting language.

Personally, i like to use C# for scripts too.
Then make the program load the script file and compile it runtime.