# How to embed VBA into your .net application

Tags: .net, wpf, vba, api

I have small excel-like app in WPF. I would like to extend it with a possibility of embedding a VBA editor into it and exposing a small api to it. Pretty much the same way as the excel.

[How to embed IronPython in a .NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208393/how-to-embed-ironpython-in-a-net-application)

Similar as this, but I would rather use VBA and not ironpython if possible.

Comment: That's a very interesting question. It must be possible, because [Auto-cad did it](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?id=770215&siteID=123112), but I have no idea how.

Comment: Project > Add Reference > COM tab > tick Microsoft Visual Basic for Application Extensibility.  Getting pretty long on the tooth, finding docs for it beyond the Offfice usage isn't so easy.

Comment: I'm not sure that really covers it @HansPassant. AFAIK, the extensibility library doesn't expose the actual runtime environment. Wouldn't it really require an reference to `VB6EXT.OLB`?

Comment: Oh wait. That *is* the extensibility library....

Comment: This might help, but I'm finding dismally little information. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302278.aspx

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964634/using-vba-in-your-own-software