# Using VBA in your own software

Tags: vba

I'd like to use Visual Basic in my software. And I wonder if it is copyright protected? Any clues would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to contact Microsoft about purchasing the VBA SDK, if they still offer this. I doubt an individual will be able to afford it though.

Comment: VBA may be tricky to include in your own app, but there are lots of other solutions, using javascript, python, php are all possibilities in your own app .  Depending on what you are using to write your software there are opensource project to add these scripting languages to your own app

Comment: @GSerg - Well, lets say, I want to write an editor that will accept and process VBA code. I do not use VBA interpreter or any other modules/software from MS - only the language itself. Would I still need to purchase VBA SDK?
Toby Allen - thank you!

Comment: No, but you would have to write a full VBA interpreter. Why the hell would you want to do that? Anyway, according to an EU court of justice decision, you can't copyright a programming language. At least not here, in the free world. Not sure about the US, that is a starnge place. Check these out for more information: [EU case - SAS VS WPL](http://www.out-law.com/articles/2013/january/computer-programming-languages-should-not-be-viewed-as-copyrightable-says-high-court-judge/) ; [US case - Google VS Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_America,_Inc._v._Google,_Inc.)

Comment: thank you vacip, valuable point!

Answer (score 1):

VBScript is easily embedded. VBA requires a license.

This is VB6/VBA code adding VBScript as a macro language.

```
    With ScriptControl1
      .Language = "VBScript"
      .UseSafeSubset = False
      .AllowUI = True
'      MsgBox "Hwnd " & .SitehWnd() & " Safe " & .UseSafeSubset() & " Timeout " & .Timeout & " State " & .State
'      MsgBox .Eval("6+5")
      .AddObject "frmSDI", frmSDI, True
    End With

Private Sub CmdRun_Click()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim A As String
    Dim B
    A = Text1.Text()
    frmSDI.ScriptControl1.AddCode A
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then ReportError "frmMacro-CmdRun", "Unable to add code."
End Sub
```

These are the VBA rules you must implement.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177324.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft used to offer the VBA SDK for download from MSDN (under filename  `en_visual_basic_for_applications_6.0_sdk_version_6.5_x86_cd_x14-97169.iso`), although it appears to have since been removed. To legally distribute an app built with the SDK, you had to buy a distribution license from Microsoft's reseller – http://summsoft.com/vba/ – but in 2007 Microsoft decided to stop selling licenses to new customers. So unless you'd already licensed it from them pre-2007, they can't legally sell the license to you, and you can't legally redistribute any code you build with the VBA SDK.