# Is it possible to add VBA programming environment to my C++ application?

Tags: c++, vba, libraries

I have an application that is written in C++ and would like to offer the user the possibility to have a VBA-programming interface (not dissimilar from the one in Excel). Is there the possibility to do that? Does a set of libraries exists for this? Is it very difficult to do?

Comment: If you just want to make your application scriptable, there are other libraries and frameworks that are easier to use and integrate (a quick search for `embeddable script languages` or similar should give you plenty of hits). Is there a specific reason you want VBA?

Comment: How set are you on VBA? There are scripting languages that may be easier to embed, for example [Lua](https://www.lua.org/) is a popular choice.

Comment: Worth noting that Excel now supports JavaScript scripting. That's a very, very strong hint. Besides, who will write the scripts? Who are the users? What language will they know? What kind of scripts will they create? Even for business users JavaScript is a more popular language nowadays. Other applications, use Python, another very popular language

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Although that said, I don't see financial services ever moving away from VBA, annoying as that may be.

Comment: @Bathsheba and yet, Excel got JavaScript support. Visual Studio has R and Python in the Data Science workload. Finance doesn't write VBA macros, it forces the IT guys to write them, the intern, or they hire consultants

Comment: Pretty similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964634/using-vba-in-your-own-software

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, but do regard it as being *extremely* difficult. As a starter for ten, your application will need a comprehensive Component Object Model interface. At that point, you would be able to use VBScript, so it might be wise to stop there.

For fully-fledged embedded VBA, you'll need to negotiate a licence with Microsoft.

Some applications (e.g. Reuters Kobra) licence the VBA interface in a similar way.